# I'm trying to WAP to convert denary to binary without using list

Tags: python

I have already seen a couple of programs for this. Just wanted to know what's wrong with this logic. It keeps on returning 'str' object does not support item assignment. I looked this up but still couldn't find a reason this occurs.I'm just a newbie so apologies in advance if I'm just overthinking things.

```
x = dec
a = 5
n = 1
remainder = str()
binary = str()
while a != 1:
    a = x // 2
    b = x % 2
    x = a
    z = str(b)
    remainder = str(remainder + z)
if a == 1:
    b = 1
    z = str(b)
    remainder = str(remainder + z)
print(remainder)
asd = len(remainder)
for y in range(1, asd + 1):
    binary[y:y + 1] = remainder[-y:-y - 1]
print("It's binary form is ", binary)
```

Comment: This is not valid Python code (what is `dec`, for example?). Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `bin(decimal_number)` will convert to binary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for y in range(1, asd + 1):
    binary[y:y + 1] = remainder[-y:-y - 1]
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error
```

What do you expect this to do?  Python strings are immutable: you cannot assign to a string slice.  You can only use the value (right-hand side of an assignment, for example), or replace the variable's entire value.

I suspect that you're trying to reverse the string.  Do it like this:

```
rev = remainder[::-1]   # Whole string, but in reverse order
```